# Using OR in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple ternary operator, where I want to return null with two different strings.

```
this.props.sportType === 'tennis' || 'soccer' ? null : <li onClick={this.props.onClick} className={styles.menuItem}>N/A</li>
```

But this doesn't quite work, unfortunately. How can I use || properly in ternary operator?

Thanks! :)

Comment: `How can I use || properly in ternary operator?` - your real problem `How can I use || properly`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeat the comparison with the second value

```
this.props.sportType === 'tennis' || this.props.sportType === 'soccer'
    ? ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use an array and see whether `sportType` is included in it:

```
['tennis', 'soccer'].includes(this.props.sportType)
? null
: <li onClick={this.props.onClick} className={styles.menuItem}>Sport</li>
```

(also, preferably indent longer expressions)

Answer (score 1):

As in a IF statement, you need to compare the "soccer" string to

```
this.props.sportType === 'tennis' || this.props.sportType === 'soccer' ? null : <li onClick={this.props.onClick} className={styles.menuItem}>N/A</li>
```

Comment: How does it differ from @Nina's answer?

Comment: No diffs, i was writting at the same time i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex

```
/^tennis|soccer$/.test(this.props.sportType) ? null : <li onClick={this.props.onClick} className={styles.menuItem}>N/A</li>
```